# Print title importing from one location to another

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, queryselector

I've created a vba script to parse the `title` of diffetent posts along with the `editing status` of those posts from a website. What I wish to do now is let my script parse the `title` from it's landing page but print the `title` at the same time when it will print the `editing status`. I do not wish to create two subs for this task. I do not even know if it is possible in vba. However, if anything unclear please check out the comment within my script.

```
Sub ImportTitleFromAnotherLocation()
    Const LINK$ = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping"
    Const prefix$ = "https://stackoverflow.com"
    Dim Http As New XMLHTTP60, Html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim editInfo As Object, I&, targetUrl$, postTile$

    With Http
        .Open "GET", LINK, False
        .send
        Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    With Html.querySelectorAll(".summary .question-hyperlink")
        For I = 0 To .Length - 1

            postTitle = .item(I).innerText 'I like this line to be transferred to the location below

            targetUrl = Replace(.item(I).getAttribute("href"), "about:", prefix)
            With Http
                .Open "GET", targetUrl, False
                .send
                Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
            End With

            R = R + 1: Cells(R, 1) = postTitle 'here I wish to use the above line like this

            Set editInfo = Html.querySelector(".user-action-time > a")
            If Not editInfo Is Nothing Then
                Cells(R, 2) = editInfo.innerText
            End If
        Next I
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting your html document in the loop. A simple way would be to use a second htmldocument variable. A more verbose way would be to store the titles before the loop, for example in an array during an additional loop, then use your i variable to index into that to retrieve each title during the existing loop.

```
Sub ImportTitleFromAnotherLocation()
    Const LINK$ = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping"
    Const prefix$ = "https://stackoverflow.com"
    Dim Http As New XMLHTTP60, Html As New HTMLDocument, Html2 As New HTMLDocument

    Dim editInfo As Object, I&, targetUrl$, postTile$
    Dim postTitle As String, r As Long
    With Http
        .Open "GET", LINK, False
        .send
        Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    With Html.querySelectorAll(".summary .question-hyperlink")
        For I = 0 To .Length - 1
            postTitle = .item(I).innerText 'I like this line to be transferred to the location below
            targetUrl = Replace$(.item(I).getAttribute("href"), "about:", prefix)

            With Http
                .Open "GET", targetUrl, False
                .send
                Html2.body.innerHTML = .responseText
            End With

            r = r + 1: ActiveSheet.Cells(r, 1) = postTitle 'here I wish to use the above line like this

            Set editInfo = Html2.querySelector(".user-action-time > a")
            If Not editInfo Is Nothing Then
                ActiveSheet.Cells(r, 2) = editInfo.innerText
            End If
        Next I
    End With
End Sub
```